# How can I do automated testing in the WCF web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, automated-tests

I have developed WCF Web service. I am working on it and continuous updating new methods. I want to add TDD for testing. When I add new methods or update existing methods some methods stops working due to new update. Moreover testing all methods also takes too much time. Is there any solution to automated testing of WCF Web service?

**Update: TDD implementation in WCF Web service will also work for me.**

Comment: You can perfectly test WCF services. How to do so is too broad for SO, buy a book on testing. And _"testing all methods also takes too much time"_ - learn about different types of tests and when to use which.

Comment: @CodeCaster Really disappointed with your answer. However appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can use two approaches.

1. Implement common unit test and cover you services methods not touching wcf infrastructure.
2. Use Visual Studio Web Performance and  Load Tests (available only in VS Ultimate).

Answer (score 0):

From your test project, just call your opertions and `Assert`